# remove show effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable my show effect for certain dialogs.  It seems, if I don't specify `show` in the initialization of a dialog, the dialog simply shows as intended.  If I specify `show` with an effect it works properly as well.  How can I return back to the initial `show` after initializing with a different animation.  I've tried

```
$dialog.dialog("option",'show',{effect:'none'});

$dialog.dialog("option",'show',{});

$dialog.dialog("option",'show',false);
```

all of these give me a weird blind effect.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle of ur code

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for the [autoOpen](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen) option?

Comment: No, I'm trying to control the animation effect.

Comment: autoOpen doesn't control the animation effect. "If set to true, the dialog will automatically open upon initialization. If false, the dialog will stay hidden until the open() method is called."

Comment: I understand, that's why I'm not looking for autoOpen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in documentation:

```
$dialog.dialog('option', 'show', null);
```

Link: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-show